# Change the class of a input field

Tags: javascript, css, forms, validation, input

Sorry. Let me rephrase:

I want js to change to class of a input field if it is left empty; Here is my code to detect a empty field:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var ctrl = document.forms["form1"]["username"];
    var x=ctrl.value;
    if (x==null || x=="") {
////////////CHANGE INPUT CLASS/////////////   
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById('username').style.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF";      
    }
}
```

i would have to css classes:

```
.inputfield {
background-color:white;
}

.inputfieldempty {
background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: There are four separate tasks in this question. Which one is giving you trouble? What code do you have so far?

Comment: I have a form which posts the contents to a php process page. I want it to post ONLY when all fields are filled. And when a field is left empty it should change bgcolor

Comment: If you want an easy way (instead of learning how it's done), youz could use the [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Comment: I think that will be easier and faster to deal with code snippets...

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript) might contain the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @Wex, actually it contains one half of the answer. The other half would be how to prevent the form to be posted if invalid.

Comment: Sorry guys for the 2 part question. Basicaly it must not post the form if the fields are empty and it should just change the class when the user leaves a field empty

Comment: how would you prevent the form from submitting using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent submitting you need to call a function for the onsubmit event of the form (e.g. `onsubmit="return checkFields()"`. In the function you will do the validations and return true or false depending on that. If the function will return false then the form will not be posted.

As part of your validations when you determine that a field's value is empty you can do the desired css changes as well. I don't know if you use vanilla javascript or a library such as jQuery in order to give more specific details.

Comment: Do i add it to the <form> or the <input type=submit>? if it is true how do you tell it to post

Comment: You add it in the form element. Simply returning true or false will make the form submit or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) for the excellent **jQuery Validation** plugin, which does exactly what you need and you don't even have to fiddle with cross-browser concerns.

If you don't want to use the plugin, I still recommend at least to use jQuery. [Here's another tutorial](http://webcloud.se/log/Form-validation-with-jQuery-from-scratch/) that goes through all the necessary steps.

Answer (score 0):

This post should take care of adding your CSS classes: [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

This post should take care of preventing forms to submit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault